# Which is best solution for p2p connections

Tags: android, protocols

I'm thinking develop android application,Where is s/he?.

If client 'A' request location of client 'B',Server connect client 'B' and get gps location of client 'B' and server response to client 'A'

Application should work in background but should not force hard to mobile device.

There should be no trafic between client and server if there is no request. Traffic should be if there is request.

Like Skype or whatsup,you can connect client everytime you call or sending message If client is on internet so that my application should work if both users on internet. İf requested client is not on internet then application should send latest known position.

For these porpose,Which protocal should I use? Http(I think no),TCP ,XMPP or android bound service implement my methodlgy?

How do I implement my applcations methods?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to offend you, but I think you should start with the fundamentals of android development and distributed systems.
However, here is my answer:

You could use HTTP, but better use HTTPS to be sure, that data is encrypted between the server and the client. 
If I were going to create such an app, I'd write a small application on the android device which transmits the position of the device, together with a unique id of the device (probably the IMEI) to a server, encoded in a HTTP(S) request.

Using HTTP would have the benefit, that you could use many different languages on server side, for example PHP (would be my choice, but you could use others).
On the server side you would need to put the recieved data into a database or some other storage.

From there it is your choice what you are going to do and how to present the data. Maybe making a small website?

Regards
Me

Comment: Using HTTP(S) how to server connect client? I remember only client can connect to server with post or get method.In my method,Client 'A' request gps data and server connect Client 'B' and get data and reponse A. In my knowlodge server cant connect to client

Comment: Oh Well, I have to admit that I got you wrong - sorry for that!
Well, this is a bit tricky, you will have to send signals periodically from the client to the server. I think I would try to use something called "UDP Hole Punching": There, the client sends a packet to the server over UDP. Now the server knows the sending IP-Adress and the source Port of client A. It now can connect on this IP / Port whenerver client B asks for the position of client A. Client B would need to do the same, to be reachable for the server if client A asks for its position.

Comment: this is not my solution.Please read my question carefully. If there is request,there should be internet trafic. If there is no request , no trafic between client and server. Look like whatsup and skype

Comment: Well, this is simply not possible. The server needs to know how he can connect to the device. And the only way how the server can do this is when the device tells him regularly where it is to find! (For example: Someone calls you on the landline but you are not at home. If the caller did not leave a message, you wouldn't know that somebody called. There needs to flow some information)!

Comment: mate developpers did that. have you ever use skype or whatsup? In whatsup,If you send messege other one see that but no messeage no traffic. In skype if you online  whatever you in background or in application otherones can call. In my method, both users should see their location if they are on internet

Comment: Well, actually skype does it in the way I discribed: By UDP hole punching: Client A connects the server. The server now knows the public ip and port of client A. now Client B connects to the server and the server tells him the IP and Port of Client A. Client B can now connec to Client A. Now Client A knows the public IP/Port of Client B too and they can communicate together.
However, now when one clients ip changes, it needs to retransmit it to the server and the whole "handshaking" starts all over again.
Search for it on google, "mate", you will find more info how it is realized in skype...

Comment: well i will consider that